# JavaFX 2: Is there a way to show a tooltip on load?

Tags: javafx-2, tooltip

Is there a way to render a tooltip on a node when the node is rendered on the UI?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

[Timing on tooltips is currently not configurable in JavaFX 2.2](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-19538).

Comment: I wish to show a callout like thing on a label in my javafx app. Had the tooltip option worked as described above, that would have been perfect. Is there any other way to tell a user something about a label, that would fade away after loading the stage and showing it for a few seconds?